# SearchBox in my google maps API is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

My searchbox used to work. But now it's not working. I didn't understand why.
Can you please give a help ?
My code is here;

```
<input id="pac-input" type="text" size="50"><div id="dvMap"style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div><script type="text/javascript">
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var marker;
var markers = [];
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { markers[i].setMap(null); }
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var place;
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map });
    for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    }
    markers.push(marker);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.setZoom(17);
});
```

Comment: what's not working, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks for your care. There are no errors. Search box used to suggest me some locations when i started typing. But right now it doesn't suggest a thing.

Comment: use this as reference : http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2NhsE/